# Double-clicking a .jar file does absolutely nothing

Tags: windows, jar, minecraft

Basically i am trying to install a preview for Optifine 1.16.1 (the downloaded file is called "preview_OptiFine_1.16.1_HD_U_G2_pre4.jar") and when i double click it, it does literally nothing? After i opened task manager, it said that a process called "Java(TM) Platform SE binary" exists and takes up 20.9 MB of ram. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Hello**, if you have Windows installed on your *PC*/*laptop* try the following steps:

Create a file called start.txt write

```
java -jar "preview_OptiFine_1.16.1_HD_U_G2_pre4.jar"
```

in the file and save it as a .bat file.
Run double click the .bat file, and it should work.

If it still does not work then try to run the .bat file as an administrator.

Have fun, I hope I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Install forge 1.16.1, then launch the game with the optifine mod in your mods folder using the 1.16.1 client, if you cannot execute the optifine file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced  similar problem earlier.

The mistake is:  computer is trying to open it with java.exe while it must open it with javaw.exe so that it can create a window.